# Server values for Visitor IP - which to check in this usecase?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, proxy, ip-address

there are other questions on this subject, but I am interested in a specific usecase.

I'm the author of a country geolocation plugin that's worked fine for years. A prob has been posted (probably IP address related); but I've had no response to a request for additional info.

Currently the plugin ONLY gets the IP address from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] because:

1. it shouldn't matter whether it contains the visitors "real" IP address or that of their proxy, as in most legitimate cases they would be the same country.
2. responses to other StackOverflow qns stated $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is the only "reliable & safe" value.

However, when using a reverse proxy (NGINX) a server's "REMOTE_ADDR" may (incorrectly?) contain localhost/server-side IP.

In such cases can I be confident that $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] will contain visitor IP/their proxy?

Bearing in mind my comment on proxy servers, should I modify the plugin to first attempt to get IP address from:

- i: 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' then ii. 'REMOTE_ADDR'

or do I need to extend further? e.g.

- i. first csv in 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP';  ii. first csv in 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'; iii. 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP'; iv. 'REMOTE_ADDR'

I assume the additional checks and validation would have no noticeable speed impact on visitors to anyone's server?

**clarification after deceze answer (thanks):**

> "exploitation by default"

It's not used for security, it tailors content based on visitor country. If someone ***spoofs*** an address they will just get content e.g. an advert, intended for another country. ***Poisoning:*** the internet relies on input forms; I can't see how IP validating an environment variable is as complicated or risky as validating comment form input.

N.B. **if you are** using IP address to block/allow by country even $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] **is not reliable**. When I checked a host it contained the "middle man" address for requests via anon proxy or VPN (try with Opera). Transparent proxy could be identified, but only by additionally checking the "spoofable" env variables.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP operates behind a proxy, then it's entirely up to the proxy configuration whether and how the actual origin address is being passed. You cannot possibly foresee all possible variable names people are going to use, **and you should not try to get the value from any arbitrary HTTP headers since that may lead to exploitation by default.** You'll have to require the server admin/user of your plugin to explicitly configure where your plugin is supposed to get the remote IP from. You can only safely default to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, anything else must be explicitly configured based on the particular setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: the plugin is not used for security and I've added a clarification to the qn. I assume my understanding is correct?

Plugin is on Wordpress.org. Many users are non-tech. Unfortunately, expecting such users to configure the plugin with unspecified variable names and devise a checking order ruleset is unrealistic; and adds complexity and risk to the plugin. That said, I had already considered on/off switches for the defined variables in my qn. However, an excess of options in settings might be confusing and off-putting.

Comment: Even if it's not important for security, if you consider the value of arbitrary HTTP headers by default that means anyone can send those arbitrary headers and get your plugin to work incorrectly. How great the consequences of that are is up to you to judge. You could dress up that configuration in all sorts of ways to make it user friendly… ask the admin questions like "Are you using CloudFlare?" and then select the known configuration for such services automatically, and offer an "advanced…" option somewhere to allow arbitrary configuration.